# How to leave/exit/deactivate a Python virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, exit, virtualenvwrapper

I'm using virtualenv and the virtualenvwrapper. I can switch between virtualenv's just fine using the `workon` command.

```
me@mymachine:~$ workon env1
(env1)me@mymachine:~$ workon env2
(env2)me@mymachine:~$ workon env1
(env1)me@mymachine:~$
```

How do I exit all virtual environments and work on my system environment again? Right now, the only way I have of getting back to `me@mymachine:~$` is to exit the shell and start a new one. That's kind of annoying. Is there a command to work on "nothing", and if so, what is it? If such a command does not exist, how would I go about creating it?

Comment: There is a command to workon "nothing" - it displays all your available virtual environments, which is pretty nifty. Just type "workon" with no arguments and hit enter. The command to leave is "deactivate", as answered below.

Comment: Does closing the shell deactivate all the environments used the shell session.
Just wanted to get an idea if  it modifies the path env variable of the windows and just leaves it like that once the shell is closed ?

Comment: @MukeshMahadev Yes, activation is only for the current shell.

Answer (score 4128, accepted):

Usually, activating a virtualenv gives you a shell function named:

```
$ deactivate
```

which puts things back to normal.

I have just looked specifically again at the code for `virtualenvwrapper`, and, yes, it too supports `deactivate` as the way to escape from all virtualenvs.

If you are trying to leave an [*Anaconda*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) environment, the command depends upon your version of `conda`. Recent versions (like 4.6) install a `conda` function directly in your shell, in which case you run:

```
conda deactivate
```

Older conda versions instead implement deactivation using a stand-alone script:

```
source deactivate
```

Comment: The “deactivate” command is not a binary, nor a script that you “source”; it is a shell alias that gets defined dynamically in your current shell by the “activate” script.

Comment: @Apreche In the meantime (almost four years later) this appears to have been [added](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command_ref.html#deactivate) to the documentation.

Comment: Would be much more intuitive if it were called "workoff" or "unworkon". Or if "workon" were called "activate". Thank goodness for alias.

Comment: @kkurian — you should suggest that on the issue tracker for `virtualenvwrapper` and maybe Doug Hellmann would consider it! Note, for those who might read these comments later, that `workon` is **NOT** a native `virtualenv` command (which is what the original question is about) but a `virtualenvwrapper` command!

Comment: @BrandonRhodes to be exact, it is not an alias, it's a function

Comment: Guess what the actual virtualenv command inside of "workon" is called?
...(spoiler warning)...
...(spoiler warning)...
...(spoiler warning)...
...(spoiler warning)...
activate!

Comment: What a f**cked up way of doing things!! Why is Python deciding that the word `deactivate` only belongs to it?

Comment: Groan again. The second time I've encountered this.

Answer (score 144):

Use:

```
$ deactivate
```

If this doesn't work, try

```
$ source deactivate
```

Anyone who knows how [Bash `source`](https://superuser.com/a/46146/3376) works will think that's odd, but some wrappers/workflows around virtualenv implement it as a complement/counterpart to `source activate`. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: `deactivate` is a function that gets created when you source the `activate` file. Your suggestion to do `source deactivate` doesn't make sense at all, as there is no file named `deactivate`

Comment: This doesn't deserve the downvotes.  See edit of selected response: source deactivate is for the anaconda environment.

Comment: It "deserves" downvotes for not meeting the SO **answer** quality standards. It's more of a comment than an answer. But, because of the 79 reputation of the poster, we should be nice and give good feedback.

Comment: @Abdul I have demonstrated how you can improve your answer quality in Revision 2 at http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29586756/revisions

Comment: this is very unhelpful if you don't have a deactivate command in your shell. I don't really understand why this would help the problem. There is no deactivate script in the virtual env.

Comment: @Anthon However, "source deactivate" works for me but "deactivate" doesn't

Comment: @Statham are you running that non-standard Anaconda installer?

Comment: @Anthon yeah, I have both anaconda2 and anaconda3 on my computer, so i have to run that, and maybe that's the reason

Answer (score 69):

I defined an [alias](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias), **workoff**, as the opposite of **workon**:

```
alias workoff='deactivate'
```

It is easy to remember:

```
[bobstein@host ~]$ workon django_project
(django_project)[bobstein@host ~]$ workoff
[bobstein@host ~]$
```

Comment: In which file? `.bashrc`?

Comment: @seyed yes, see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/17538/215820) for an example of alias in `~/.bashrc`

Comment: I like this alias. Reminds me of the Karate Kid (waxon; waxoff)

Comment: @C0deH4cker: I signed into SO and came back to this question just to +1 your comment :p

Answer (score 44):

To activate a Python virtual environment:

```
$cd ~/python-venv/
$./bin/activate
```

To deactivate:

```
$deactivate
```

Comment: In terminal on OS X10.11.1, I seem to have to use:
`$source activate`

Comment: I didn't need source. I did `$cd /to/dir/i/want/my/virtualenv/installed` then `$virtualenv name_i_want_for_it` then `$. name_i_want_for_it/bin/activate` virtualenv still seems a bit off to me. Needs to be improved...

Comment: "source" is the same as the  "." command.. either can be used to source a file

Answer (score 34):

Running `deactivate [name of your environment]` is able to exit/deactivate from your python environment.

Example with python3.6 Windows 10 in PowerShell:

```
PS C:\Users\kyrlon\Desktop> py -m venv env1
PS C:\Users\kyrlon\Desktop> .\env1\Scripts\activate
(env1) PS C:\Users\kyrlon\Desktop> deactivate env1
PS C:\Users\kyrlon\Desktop> py -m venv env1
```

Example with python3.9 on Linux Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop:

```
kyrlon@pc1:~$ python3 -m venv venv1
kyrlon@pc1:~$ source venv1/bin/activate
(venv1) kyrlon@pc1:~$ deactivate venv1
kyrlon@pc1:~$
```

Comment: I had a curious situation where I couldn't deactivate, so solution wise I just closed the terminal in that situation. However, thanks for mentioning that explicitly naming the python venv also works. I don't if it would have worked, since I can't reproduce the original issue, but I just tested that this works on its own on Python 3.11 as well

Answer (score 27):

In MacOs ventura -

to activate -

```bash
 sudo chmod -R 755  ./venv/bin
 source venv/bin/activate
```

to deactivate -

```bash
deactivate
```

Answer (score 14):

I found that when within a Miniconda3 environment I had to run:

```
conda deactivate
```

Neither `deactivate` nor `source deactivate` worked for me.

Comment: `deactivate` was for `virtualenv`, and `source deactivate` is for old conda on Linux. `conda deactivate` is a good cross-platform way for conda envs (not virtualenvs)

Answer (score 12):

For my particular case, I go to to the working directory

```
CD /myworkingdirectory
```

Then I activate my env like this:

```
my-env/scripts/activate
```

From this same working folder (`/myworkingdirectory`) to deactivate, I tried this but it does nothing:

```
my-env/scripts/deactivate
```

This does work:

```
deactivate
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use `virtualenvwrapper` in order to ease the way you work with `virtualenv`.

Installing `virtualenvwrapper`:

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

If you are using a standard shell, open your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` if you use [Oh My Zsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell#Oh_My_Zsh). Add these two lines:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

To activate an existing virtualenv, use command `workon`:

```
$ workon myenv
(myenv)$
```

In order to deactivate your virtualenv:

```
(myenv)$ deactivate
```

Here is [my tutorial](http://levipy.com/virtualenv-and-virtualenvwrapper-tutorial/), step by step on how to install virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper.

Comment: I see little difference compared to built-in virtualenv

Comment: @NamGVU Notice the `workon` command, it works from any directory.

Comment: As mentioned in another post's comment (and Stackoverflow doesn't have a practical way to point to it) you cannot use `deactivate` in a shell script without first sourcing the script that defines this function (in that case you will have that _command not found..._ error)

Comment: @levi I think it is "deactivate myenv" instead (not simple "deactivate")

Answer (score 11):

**Using the `deactivate` feature provided by the venv's `activate` script requires you to trust the deactivation function to be properly coded** to cleanly reset all environment variables back to how they were before— taking into account not only the *original activation*, but also any *switches*, *configuration*, or *other work* you may have done in the meantime.

It's probably fine, but it does introduce a new, non-zero risk of leaving your environment modified afterwards.

However, it's not technically possible for a process to directly alter the environment variables of its parent, **so we can use a separate sub-shell to be absolutely sure** our `venv`s don't leave any residual changes behind:

---

### To activate:

`$ bash --init-file PythonVenv/bin/activate`

- This starts a new shell around the `venv`. Your original `bash` shell remains unmodified.

### To deactivate:

`$ exit` OR `[CTRL]`+`[D]`

- This exits the entire shell the `venv` is in, and drops you back to the original shell from before the activation script made any changes to the environment.

---

### Example:

```
[user@computer ~]$ echo $VIRTUAL_ENV
No virtualenv!

[user@computer ~]$ bash --init-file PythonVenv/bin/activate

(PythonVenv) [user@computer ~]$ echo $VIRTUAL_ENV
/home/user/PythonVenv

(PythonVenv) [user@computer ~]$ exit
exit

[user@computer ~]$ echo $VIRTUAL_ENV
No virtualenv!
```

Answer (score 8):

`$ conda deactivate` 
or
 `$ source deactivate`

would work. 
 If it doesn't work, try `deactivate [name of your environment]` instead.

Comment: For me deactivate [name of my env] worked.

Answer (score 6):

Since the `deactivate` function created by sourcing `~/bin/activate` cannot be discovered by the usual means of looking for such a command in `~/bin`, you may wish to create one that just executes the function `deactivate`.

The problem is that a script named `deactivate` containing a single command `deactivate` will cause an endless loop if accidentally executed while not in the venv. A common mistake.

This can be avoided by only executing `deactivate` if the function exists (i.e. has been created by sourcing `activate`).

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -Ff deactivate  && deactivate
```

Answer (score 4):

I use [zsh-autoenv](https://github.com/Tarrasch/zsh-autoenv) which is based off [autoenv](https://github.com/kennethreitz/autoenv).

> [zsh-autoenv](https://github.com/Tarrasch/zsh-autoenv) automatically
>   sources (known/whitelisted) `.autoenv.zsh` files, typically used in
>   project root directories. It handles "enter" and leave" events,
>   nesting, and stashing of variables (overwriting and restoring).

Here is an example:

```
; cd dtree 
Switching to virtual environment: Development tree utiles
;dtree(feature/task24|✓); cat .autoenv.zsh       
# Autoenv.
echo -n "Switching to virtual environment: "
printf "\e[38;5;93m%s\e[0m\n" "Development tree utiles"
workon dtree
# eof
dtree(feature/task24|✓); cat .autoenv_leave.zsh 
deactivate
```

So when I leave the `dtree` directory, the virtual environment is automatically exited.

`"Development tree utiles"` is just a name… No hidden mean linking to the Illuminati in here.

Answer (score 4):

I my case, I was able to activate virtual environment using `env-name\scripts\activate` and deactivate it using `deactivate`. However, after running update on my windows PC `deactivate` was no longer recognized as an internal or external command. What I used from that moment onward is `env-name\scripts\deactivate` and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while working on an installer script. I took a look at what the *bin/activate_this.py* did and reversed it.

Example:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys

# Path to virtualenv
venv_path = os.path.join('/home', 'sixdays', '.virtualenvs', 'test32')

# Save old values
old_os_path = os.environ['PATH']
old_sys_path = list(sys.path)
old_sys_prefix = sys.prefix


def deactivate():
    # Change back by setting values to starting values
    os.environ['PATH'] = old_os_path
    sys.prefix = old_sys_prefix
    sys.path[:0] = old_sys_path


# Activate the virtualenvironment
activate_this = os.path.join(venv_path, 'bin/activate_this.py')
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))


# Print list of pip packages for virtualenv for example purpose
import pip
print str(pip.get_installed_distributions())

# Unload pip module
del pip

# Deactivate/switch back to initial interpreter
deactivate()

# Print list of initial environment pip packages for example purpose
import pip
print str(pip.get_installed_distributions())
```

I am not 100% sure if it works as intended. I may have missed something completely.

Comment: if deactivate resets value of environment path, system path, default prompt then your deactivate function is good approach. I like your script. Already given +1.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how to exit some python environment I would just run

```
bash --norc
```

as there is a risk you missed deleting that code for entering to some python environment, which something such as conda/mamba already installed  into your `.bashrc` The conda/mamba enters environments the same way you can run bash inside bash. Default installation forces base environment to be activated by default, which drives me crazy as it might break lot of things, to exit it you just type

```
mamba deactivate
```

But you can configure conda in a way that you activate it only when you use it. Then if you e.g. type

```
mamba activate env
(env)mamba activate base
(base)mamba activate base
(base)mamba activate xy
```

You will actually be in nested environment `(xy)` and  `(xy) -deactivate-> (base) -deactivate-> (base) -deactivate-> (env) -deactivate-> no conda/mamba`.

So if you are in some environment, do not know how much nested it is and you want to get base environment, you can also use

```
mamba activate base
```