# Is there a way to deactivate a virtualenv inside python interpreter? i.e. analogous of deactivate_this

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have this script (this is the beginning of a wsgi script for openshift applications). This script activates a virtualenv using the in-python system environment.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

virtenv = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_DIR'] + '/virtenv/'
virtualenv = os.path.join(virtenv, 'bin/activate_this.py')
try:
    execfile(virtualenv, dict(__file__=virtualenv))
except IOError:
    pass
```

What's the opposite? i.e.: is there an analogous way to do a "deactivate_this"? (a file like that does not seem to exist in any of my created virtualenvs)

This means: I don't want to reinvent the wheel. I'm asking if there's a prepared command line for that.

Comment: have you tried subprocess?

Comment: Actually, no. Does that let me alter the environment variables as well?

Comment: you just want to deactivate the virtualenv yes?

Comment: yes. this script (activate_this) alters the environment and the underlying shell. is there an already-made way to do the opposite?

Comment: What specifically is the activation setting that is causing a problem? There are other ways of activating a virtual environment if using mod_wsgi. So helping us to understand what the original problem is would be better than asking us what you think is the solution.

Comment: I'm having some problems using openshift, and have to run nested commands. Simple calls to `os.system` passing 'bin/activate' and 'deactivate' did not work for me (they produced no effect). So I wanted to embed both activation and deactivation in the interpreter itself.

Comment: Note the reason running `bin/activate` and `deactivate` had no (visible) effect is because they run the sub-shell in a new subprocess, and then exit. So they have no (direct) effect on the running process. You'd need to do something like `os.system("bin/activate; my_program.py")`

Comment: Yes, that's a good alternative. But I would need a way to share actual data (python objects) with the executed script. that's the reason why I did not took that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the short answer is No.

The medium answer is "Not unless you have saved the state of the environment before executing activate_this.py".

Perhaps a way to achieve what you want is to separate the parts of your app that need to run in the venv from those that don't. Then use a subprocess to activate the venv and run whatever you want, when the subprocess terminates, your original process (in the original environment) can resume.

NB This post ([How to leave/exit/deactivate a python virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990754/how-to-leave-a-python-virtualenv)) suggests the activation may provide a shell function to put-everything-back. You'd need to check if your `activate_this.py` script provides anything similar, though it sounds like you have already checked this.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer (it fits as I asked), and adding my answer with what I have just found now.

Comment: Thank you - sounds interesting!

Comment: It is there :) if you have issues like this some day.

Answer (score 2):

This is a complement to the answer @TomDalton gave. Althought there's no an automatically provided way to do this, there are means provided by the `activate_this` script.

First, it is important to remember that this line:

```
execfile(virtualenv, dict(__file__=virtualenv))
```

is calling the function without passing a dictionary for globals nor a dictionary for locals. This will imply that the execution context will be the current globals (i.e. the one from the calling line) and locals objects. **such line will alter the variables we currently have -- will override the calling environment** [See here for docs about](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile).

In that way, since variables are overriden, `activate_this` gives us some variables like:

```
old_os_path = os.environ['PATH']
#the previous PATH

prev_sys_path = list(sys.path)
#the old Python Path

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    site_packages = os.path.join(base, 'Lib', 'site-packages')
else:
    site_packages = os.path.join(base, 'lib', 'python%s' % sys.version[:3], 'site-packages')
prev_sys_path = list(sys.path)
import site
site.addsitedir(site_packages)
#site_packages is the extended venv's packages dir.
#sys.path is affected here

sys.real_prefix = sys.prefix
#the old system prefix
```

So we can restore such variables if we want a manual deactivation:

```
import sys, os, site
sys.path[:0] = prev_sys_path #will also revert the added site-packages
sys.prefix = sys.real_prefix
os.setenv('PATH', old_os_path)
```

Comment: Nice. It's a shame activate_this.py doesn't provide a function to do this automatically, but I think it wasn't designed for this job.

Comment: activate_this was designed for, specifically, that purpose (otherwise the script would not exist). I think it would be wise to recommend the patch (it's a nonbreaking patch) with such function. I'm trying that now.

Comment: Sorry, I meant for being able to deactivate the environment. If it was designed for that, then expecting you to use the commands found above is non-obvious and it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.

Comment: I did not express myself correctly. `activate_this` was designed to act in the same python path. extending it to create a `deactivate` function is straightforward. It is a pity these variables are not documented and so are able to change without prior notice.