# Why can't I "deactivate" pyenv / virtualenv? How to "fix" installation

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv, pyenv

I am on a freshly installed *Ubuntu 16.04* and in view of developing with recent versions of *pandas* I installed *Python 3.6.0* using a virtual environment.

A reason for choosing 3.6.0 was because I read somewhere that this version of Python could deal with virtual environments natively, i.e. without installing anything else [anyway to install 3.6.0 itself without replacing the system wide Python, which would have been almost surely wrong, I actually had to provide a virtual environment before].

I did it optimistically thinking that everything would go in the right direction (including my knowledge) and so, without caring too much about the differences between: pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv, pyvenv, etc...
So I don't remember well what I installed, anyway I used only `apt` and `pip`/`pip3`, trying to confine changes within the virtualenv as soon as it became available.

I loosely followed this [tutorial](http://levipy.com/virtualenv-and-virtualenvwrapper-tutorial/) except (maybe) that I didn't create a directory for the virtualenvs (the `$ mkdir ~/.virtualenvs` command).

Now my user is stuck within the `(general)` environment and I can't get out.

### Situation

Right from the start after the login, without activating any environment, Bash gives me a modified prompt, and it seems I can't get the usual prompt by `deactivate`, `source deactivate`, etc...

```bash
(general) $ deactivate
pyenv-virtualenv: deactivate must be sourced. Run 'source deactivate' instead of 'deactivate'
(general) $ source deactivate
pyenv-virtualenv: deactivate 3.6.0/envs/general
(general) $ pyvenv deactivate
pyenv: pyvenv: command not found

The `pyvenv` command exists in these Python versions: 3.6.0

(general) $
```

You see that the `(general)` prefix remains in the prompt.

I have also had symptoms that this `pyenv`/`virtualenv` setup is affecting system activities (e.g. while trying to install `hplip` from the command line, the installer got confused when trying to recognize my OS, and ultimately failed - I had to do it from another user, and then it worked), so I need to revert this to a clean state.

NB. I am not that sure that my installation is really that wrong, maybe it's just me issuing the wrong commands or some common pitfall I have incurred in.

### **The questions**

- How can I `deactivate` the (general) environment?
- How can I tell if my installation is wrong, and how can I *fix* it?
- Wow can I safely revert from this installation and get to a more proper one?

I have already read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990754/how-to-leave-exit-deactivate-a-python-virtualenv) but it wasn't so tied to my case

[This one](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/4hsudz/pyvenv_vs_virtualenv/) seems more related, in that it highlights that

- `python venv` should be preferred;
- it is available on Python >=3.3;
- Ubuntu Xenial doesn't have it already installed by default;
- it gives package names to install it.

But still I am unsure of what to uninstall before installing them in case.

### More info

Here are the outputs of TAB completions, commands, and a directory listing, to show a bit of which environment I am in:

```bash
(general) $ cat .py <TAB>
.pyenv/          .python_history  
(general) $ cat .pyenv/ <TAB>
.agignore     completions/  LICENSE       shims/        versions/
bin/          CONDUCT.md    Makefile      src/          .vimrc
cache/        .git/         plugins/      test/         
CHANGELOG.md  .gitignore    pyenv.d/      .travis.yml   
COMMANDS.md   libexec/      README.md     version       
(general) $ cat .pyenv/version
general
(general) $ ls -l ~/.pyenv/versions
totale 12
drwxrwxr-x  3 myuser myuser 4096 apr 20 13:50 ./
drwxrwxr-x 13 myuser myuser 4096 apr 20 13:50 ../
drwxr-xr-x  7 myuser myuser 4096 apr 20 13:50 3.6.0/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 myuser myuser   48 apr 20 13:50 general -> /home/myuser/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/envs/general/
```

I tried listing what installed, but I'm afraid that with `pip3 list` the answer I get is for the env where I am stuck, and that this is masking anything that I installed *before* getting to it.

May it just be that I mistakenly installed `pyenv` from my home directory? Would it be enough to delete/move the `.pyenv` directory? I am not confident enough to do it without asking.

Comment: I checked that I haven't installed neither `pyenv`, nor `virtualenv` nor even `virtualenvwrapper`. So I must have worked with `python3 -m venv` only. Is it correct if I have a `.pyenv` folder in my home directory?

Comment: Did you resolve this? having exactly the same issue.

Comment: Yes the problem is solved now. I removed pyenv completely from my user space by removing the `.pyenv` directory. Only after that I understood that it must have been because of the command `pyenv general xxx`, which afaicu just creates a `.pyenv-version` file in your home directory. So, first of all try, removing that

Answer (score 9):

It was deactivated when I used this command: `pyenv shell .`

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT-[22/11/22]---> BELOW ANSWER IS FROM 2018 - maybe i never got to DEACTIVATE and did only manage to UN-INSTALL**

The way to DEACTIVATE the default PyEnv General is --pyenv uninstall 3.6.0/envs/general

```
pyenv-virtualenv: remove /home/dhankar/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/envs/general? y
dhankar@dhankar-VPCEB44EN:~/.pyenv$
```

to doubly ensure that the PyENV has been removed --

```
dhankar@dhankar-VPCEB44EN:~/.pyenv$ pyenv versions
pyenv: version `general' is not installed (set by /home/dhankar/.pyenv/version)
  system
  3.6.0
  3.6.5
dhankar@dhankar-VPCEB44EN:~/.pyenv$
```

Also so that its documented - am sharing the terminal output of the same command , earlier before the Un-Install.

```
(general) dhankar@dhankar-VPCEB44EN:~/.pyenv$ pyenv versions
  system
  3.6.0
  3.6.0/envs/general
  3.6.5
* general (set by /home/dhankar/.pyenv/version)
(general) dhankar@dhankar-VPCEB44EN:~/.pyenv$
```

Comment: Uh, no, this doesn't just deactivate it, it removes it entirely.

Comment: Yes - it did remove it entirely is what i can also read now . Probably that is not what was required to be done . I should remove that answer or Edit it maybe .

Answer (score 1):

Your mental model of what these modules do is wrong.

`pyenv` doesn't really have a "deactivate" feature. It lets you choose between a number of independent Python installations, but you would basically always be using one of them - unless you get rid of `pyenv` entirely. `pyenv shell .` effectively deactivates `pyenv` for the time being in the current shell instance, and if you want to remove it from your configuration entirely, you want to remove the `pyenv` commands from your shell's login files: they would typically look something like

```
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

where the latter is an optional add-on which you might not have installed.

You *can* mix `pyenv` with regular virtual environments; for example, you could run `pyenv shell 3.8.9` and then with that active run `python -m venv thisenv` which will create `thisenv` in the current directory with a link to the selected Python version; then running `source thisenv/bin/activate` will activate the virtual environment, so that `python` or `python3` runs the Python version you had active in `pyenv` when you created the environment, and you can subsequently `deactivate` that to return to whatever you had before.

As a quick hack, you can also run `$(pyenv root)/versions/3.8.9/bin/python -m venv thisenv` to create the environment without touching the `pyenv shell` setting.

The [`pyenv-virtualenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv) add-on plugin has its own set of features, with a slightly different set of use cases. You create those with `pyenv virtualenv`, activate with `pyenv activate`, and deactivate with `pyenv deactivate`. These environments are stored alongside the `pyenv` Python versions in a central place in your home directory, not in the current directory.