# virtualenv enable the environment global

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am working in the environment when activate the `ll_env`

```
me at me in ~/desktop/django/learning_log
$ source ll_env/bin/activate
(ll_env) 
me at me in ~/desktop/django/learning_log
$
```

When change to the parent directory, it still is in the scope of the virtual environment:

```
(ll_env) 
me at me in ~/desktop/django
$
```

I assumed that `ll_env` might disappear when jump out of the directory where environment files lives

How Django enable the environment global?

Comment: `source ll_env/bin/activate` runs a script in the context of your shell. You’re still in the same shell despite changing directories. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990754/how-to-leave-exit-deactivate-a-python-virtualenv

Comment: This doesn't have *anything at all* to do with Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the present working directory that determines your environment. To jump out of the virtual environment, you need to deactivate it.

Using the command: `deactivate`

Answer (score 1):

It may seem unintuitive at first, but it's important to understand that the current directory is not related to the active virtualenv. The active virtualenv determines where python should look for installed dependencies, and where it should install new dependencies to. It places that directory *on your path*, which is all that really matters in the context of working with a given virtualenv.

This means that you can `cd` anywhere on your system, do a `pip install foo`, and know that `foo` will be installed to a known location for the current venv, not to the directory you happen to be sitting in right now.

Answer (score 0):

`virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` give you access to a function called `deactivate` to stop using the virtual environment.

```
$ deactivate
```

It's different with `Anaconda environment`, You will deactivate it with two-word command:

```
$ source deactivate
```