# Powerline - how to remove "(e) base" from Terminal prompt?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal, powerline

I've followed the instructions presented on:

- https://medium.freecodecamp.org/jazz-up-your-bash-terminal-a-step-by-step-guide-with-pictures-80267554cb22

I've jazzed up my terminal, **but am running into an issue where my terminal consistently shows `(e) base` as part of the prompt.**

[image: Image of Terminal]

Google and https://powerline.readthedocs.io/en/master/ have not led me to an answer as of yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executing `source deactivate` removed (e) base.

Answer via: [How to leave/exit/deactivate a python virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990754/how-to-leave-exit-deactivate-a-python-virtualenv)

> If you are trying to leave an Anaconda environment, the procedure is a
>   bit different: run the two-word command source deactivate since they
>   implement deactivation using a stand-alone script.