# python `deactivate` command can't exit virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm on macOS Catalina [10.15]. Here is what I get when try to deactivate:

```
(django-learning) ~/git/stats-k8s/k8s-monitor (master) $ deactivate
DeprecationWarning: 'source deactivate' is deprecated. Use 'conda deactivate'.
(django-learning) ~/git/stats-k8s/k8s-monitor (master) $
(django-learning) ~/git/stats-k8s/k8s-monitor (master) $
(django-learning) ~/git/stats-k8s/k8s-monitor (master) $
(django-learning) ~/git/stats-k8s/k8s-monitor (master) $ conda deactivate

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda deactivate'.
To initialize your shell, run
...    
IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
(django-learning) ~/git/stats-k8s/k8s-monitor (master) $
```

I already looked at question: [How to leave/exit/deactivate a Python virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990754/how-to-leave-exit-deactivate-a-python-virtualenv) but did not help.

Comment: This looks like you're using `conda`, not standard `virtualenv`.

Comment: Did you activate this environment in the first place using conda or virtualenv? These are not the same thing.

Comment: Just found that the issue was with one shell[which I exited already]. Possibly, that was because I was trying to activate and deactivate my virtualenv using `direnv`.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that conda is is interfering with virtualenv on your setup. Did you install conda in the virtualenv?

Note that you can also safely close your terminal window and open a new one without using `deactivate`.

You might also try activating a different virtual environment. You can do this without deactivating first. Then you may be able to deactivate from the other environment.

Comment: At least for upstream virtualenv on systems with POSIX-y shells (can't speak to conda, which the OP's output implies they're using), `deactivate` is a shell function that `activate` defines; it's not a separate script.

Comment: It is on Windows, interesting.

Comment: Just as @CharlesDuffy mentioned, I can find a deactivate script on the <vitualenv>/bin folder.

Comment: @gilch, that makes sense, since in Windows, batch files are executed in-process (which you have to use `source` or an equivalent to get in the UNIX  world).