# os.getenv returns empty output - python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, operating-system, python-os

I am new to python and encountering some issues while executing os commands.

I have set my `environment variables` like as shown below

```
SPARK_HOME = '/opt/spark'
HAIL_HOME  = '/opt/hail/hail'
```

When I type `os.getenv('SPARK_HOME')`, I get the below output

```
'/opt/spark/'
```

But when I type `os.getenv('HAIL_HOME')`, I get **blank output**

Please note that I type the above two commands from a virtual environment using jupyter notebook.

1. Why it works for `spark` and returns empty for `hail`

Can guide me with this issue?

Comment: HAIL_HOME should be 'HAIL_HOME', a string identifier not a variable.

Comment: Sorry, updated the post. Even with `HAIL_HOME`, It returns empty output

Comment: You may debug program's env variables by printing `os.environ`. If what you look for is missing there, you should probably add command or script that sets env variables and starts your app.

Comment: Can you please help me with the second part of your comment? which is `you should probably add command or script that sets env variables and starts your app`

Comment: May I know why the item that I am looking for is missing?

Comment: Env variables are set by another program probably the shell. If an env variable is missing, you should investigate at one level below, where python script is started/executed. Thats why, it could be useful to add steps about how you set env variables and run python script.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I set these variables in my python program jupyter notebook `SPARK_HOME = '/opt/spark'
HAIL_HOME  = '/opt/hail/hail'`

Comment: but don't know why I am able to get the path of (os.getenv) for one variable and not for the other

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216475/discussion-between-the-great-and-sardok).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our discussion on chat, identified several issues.

Variable setting is confused with env variable setting. So correct way to set them should be like:

```
os.putenv('SPARK_HOME', '/opt/spark')
os.putenv('HAIL_HOME', '/opt/hail/hail')
```

Even the mistaken env variable set attempts, SPARK_HOME shows the correct value because jupyter process inherits that variable from the shell.