# Visual Studio Code with Python for Windows AND Anaconda

Tags: python, visual-studio, anaconda3

I'm trying to use Visual Studio Code with both Anaconda and Python for Windows.

I have both installed, and I have the visual studio code extensions for both.
But no matter what I do now the Conda Base gets activated -

(base) PS C:\Users

even though the Python for Windows is the selected version

[image]

or if I try to activate an environment I get a mix of both, the venv with python for windows and the conda base activated.
(venv_iocparser) (base) PS C:\Users\

The settings.json file in this folder only has python for windows in the 'python.pythonPath'; with no mention of conda, but still activates the conda base.

Does anyone know a good article that walks through setting VSCode up with both?  With python for windows as the default?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to leave/exit/deactivate a Python virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990754/how-to-leave-exit-deactivate-a-python-virtualenv)

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue. Its most likely since you installed VS Code with Anaconda, for some reason or another it just assumes thats what env you want when starting it.

To get out of it just run `$ conda deactivate` and then activate whatever env you want after that. I fixed it by changing the PATH for the python to only point at the non-conda versions though. I also had uninstalled it all and reinstalled it all at one point though.