# How to exit from anaconda prompt and go back to cmd level?

Tags: cmd, anaconda, windows-10

How to exit from anaconda prompt and go back to cmd level ?

I run to open anaconda prompt :
`%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\folder\folder\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat activate tf_2_gpu`

could I 'unload' anaconda and go back to usual cmd dialog console ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to leave/exit/deactivate a Python virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990754/how-to-leave-exit-deactivate-a-python-virtualenv)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On my Windows 10 box, `conda deactivate` works.