# What do I do if I ran source mypython/bin/activate in my root directory?

Tags: python, conda, virtualenv, python-venv, python-packaging

I realized that since I used conda to install everything, all I had to do was write out

`conda activate virtualenvironmentname`

But being the silly monkey I am, I went and cd.. until I was in the most root(iest?) directory and ran `source mypython/bin/activate`

Is there a chance that I broke my computer?

As you can clearly see, I am a monkey who is new to computer science.

Comment: With virtual environments you can always `deactivate` them. You can take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/990779/11286032) for more details on deactivating a `venv`.

Comment: If you only activated the Python virtual environment, but did not install anything (with *pip*  or *conda*) while it was active, then most likely nothing of consequence happened. Deactivate (or close the terminal session), and you can start again cleanly from scratch.